# Coding Categorical Variables

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

Suppose I am building a linear model in R. I will be doing standard OLS. I have 10 dummy variables (predictors) that correspond to different regions. 6 of these regions are in California, and the other 4 are in Texas. For example for my Northern California dummy variable is a 1 if the observation comes from California and 0 if not. I was thinking of creating a categorical variable with the values 1:10 with each number corresponding to a different region. Would this affect my analysis negatively in any way? I have a feeling that this would just distort the interpretation of my estimated coefficient. I also have a dummy variable for California and Texas.

Comment: Here's a blog article I wrote about interpreting categorical variables in R: http://anythingbutrbitrary.blogspot.com/2012/04/lm-function-with-categorical-predictors.html. You have choices about how you want to code your categorical variables into dummy vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you code the analysis, that could cause undesirable consequences. If you specify that your categorical variable is a `factor`, it'll work fine as a nominal variable: the `lm` function will create dummy variables for you. If you store the variable as a `numeric` vector, `lm` will effectively test a linear contrast of your regions as differing on the outcome variable in the order your code specifies, and by equally-spaced amounts. You probably don't intend to do that. So if `region` is your categorical variable with values `1:10`, code it something like this: `lm(y~factor(region))` if you want to have dummy codes created for you in [r](/questions/tagged/r). Better yet, just store `region` as a `factor`-type object.